# How to change the intent on a TabSpec

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

Here is the scenario:
I have an activity with 4 tabs, each tab with a different intent, each intent with a different activity.
Works perfectly.

What I need is, to somehow change the intent on one of the tabs.
It would be as simple as adding extra parameters to the Intent that is used on the `TabSpec.setContent(intent)`, but I have not found a way to retrieve that intent to change it.

The specific action I'm trying to do is: from another activity (that is inside the content of another tab) I call it's parent (the `TabActivity`) to open a different tab AND add some custom data to that tab's activity.

I can change the tab without a problem, but I haven't found a way to pass the extra parameters from one activity to the other, since the original intent used to create the `TabSpec` had no extra parameters.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Is there a way to replace the `TabSpec` content's intent?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to find a way to pass values between activities you can override the Application class.

Way to use app context.

Extend the application class and add your values as its attributes. In any activity, if you call the below code, it will return a singleton.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
```

To make this work you need to add this to the application tag of the manifest file

```
 android:name=".MyApplication"
```

This method is used to pass values around the app when sending through intent is not possible.

To remove the tab, you will need to use the clearAllTabs() method and add the tabs again. The above code should be better.

Comment: What I need is kinda very specific, it's basically when a ListView is empty, it provides a button to continue your navigation, but that navigation is passed to the `TabActivity` that then switches the tab, but it should also pass some extra arguments the that new activity. Isn't creating an `Application` for that a little overkill?

Comment: You are not creating an application you are subclassing it to hold your values. There is a default application even if you dont overide it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm storing a reference to an intent in the TabActivity

```
mGalleryTabIntent = new Intent(this, AnActivity.class);
spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec(TAB_GALLERY).setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.footer_gallery),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gallery_icon_sel)).setContent(mGalleryTabIntent); 

public Intent getStoredTabIntent(){
    return mGalleryTabIntent;
  }
```

Then, when from a child I want to navigate to another tab passing an Extra along with the Intent

```
    MainTabActivity parent = (MainTabActivity)getParent();
    parent.getStoredTabIntent().putExtra(AnActivity.START_VIEW, AnActivity.PAGE_TWO);

    //Navigate to the tab
    parent.getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(AnActivity.TAB_GALLERY);
```

Then, in AnActivity's onCreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null && extras.containsKey(START_VIEW)){
  switch (extras.getInt(START_VIEW)) {
    case PAGE_TWO:
      doSomething();
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  //Erase the Extra so that navigating to this Tab always displays the standard view unless specified otherwise
  MainTabActivity parent = (MainTabActivity)getParent();
  parent.getStoredTabIntent().putExtra(AnActivity.START_VIEW, "");
}else{
  doStandardStuff();
}
```

The Application solution is also good, but I don't think I'll be needing it for anything else, thus I'd rather stick with Activities.

Comment: Yeah I ended up implementing it pretty much like you did. It was a specific case, so I added a specific solution. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
TabSpec tabspec1;

private void createTabHost() {

    // initialize tabHost
    tabHost = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
    tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());

    // create tab1
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class).addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("myData",
                ObjData);
    tabspec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator(Utilities
                    .prepareTabView(this, "Title"))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec1 );

    // create tab2
       ...
}
```

method that changes the content of that activity placed in your tab:

```
private void reloadTabSpec1() {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class).addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.putExtra("myData", ObjData);
        tabspec1.setContent(i);

        // needed for refresh :(
        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tabspec2.getTag());
        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tabspec1.getTag());

}
```

Comment: So basically you're storing all the `TabSpec`s instances in the `TabActivity`? Is that a good practice?